# JavaFX DatePicker: can it be Day and Month only, without Year?

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8

Does the JavaFX `DatePicker` permit a yearless date, one that has a day and a month only? Nothing in the API seems to suggest that it is possible.

Sample use-case: an event that occurs every year on the same month and day,e.g. Valentine's Day or someone's birthday but they decline to give their age.

Comment: It relies on a `LocalDate` which requires a year so I don't think so. Not sure about the possible work-arounds. Hide the year part with CSS?

Comment: Might be an interesting finger exercise to write a MonthDayPicker ... (MonthDay is what you are after, if I understand you correctly)

Comment: Workarounds to make `DatePicker` fit would be difficult. You'd want to hide the "day of week" columns headers as well as the year, and you'd need to make sure it always presented it as a leap year, and even then... You probably want to implement this yourself as a subclass of `ComboBoxBase<MonthDay>`. See the [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/8875fb635616/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control) for `DatePicker` and [skin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/8875fb635616/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin)

Answer (score 1):

It would be highly illogical to have a DatePicker without a year, given the simple example that the month you are asking this question in, february 2016, is a leap year and this month has 29 days. How could the DatePicker possibly render this correctly if it does not know the year?

Comment: it could show all possible values, like MonthDay :-)